# tkinter Window unresposive while getting data from API

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter program, and it gets some data from API. When the internet connection is slow, it can take a really long time. The tkinter window becomes unresponsive. To stop it I have to force close the program. How do I avoid this?

I have a function which is called that retrieves data from the API. I want to be able to stop that function while still keeping the program and tkinter window running.

[image]

After uploading the image, I upload that to the API(which obviously takes a bit of time), and after getting the response, pastes the relevant info retrieved into a txt file and opens it.

Comment: I would use a thread for. Could you provide some code of how you read the API. So we can give some suggestions to solve it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread for the call and a recursive event check until the call is done.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

    def api_call(self, time):
        sleep(time)
        print('API call done')
        self.api_result = 10

    def on_button_click(self):
        self.button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.api_thread = Thread(target=self.api_call, args=(3,))
        self.api_thread.start()
        self.button_update()

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.api_thread = None
        self.api_result = None

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Send', command=self.on_button_click)
        self.button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    def button_update(self):
        if self.api_result is not None:
            if self.api_thread.is_alive():
                self.api_thread.join(timeout=2)
            self.button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
            self.api_thread = None
            self.api_result = None
        else:
            self.button.after(500, self.button_update)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    aplication = App()
    aplication.mainloop()
```